# SQL: Relating rows base on relative sequence of non-matching data

Tags: t-sql

So I'm sure this is probably a duplicate question, but I haven't been able to find the right post with an answer. Looking for a solution that works in T-SQL.

The problem I am trying to solve is relating two tables with loosely coupled data. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE things1 (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  parentgroup CHAR(1),
  datecreated DATETIME NOT NULL)
GO

INSERT INTO things1
SELECT 1, 'A', '2018-10-01 01:00:00.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A' '2018-10-01 01:00:02.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A', '2018-10-01 01:00:02.345'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'B', '2018-10-01 01:00:01.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'B', '2018-10-01 01:00:03.000'
GO

CREATE TABLE things2 (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  parentgroup CHAR(1),
  datecreated DATETIME NOT NULL)
GO

INSERT INTO things2
SELECT 1, 'A', '2018-10-01 01:04:00.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A' '2018-10-01 01:05:12.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A', '2018-10-01 01:05:02.345'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A', '2018-10-01 01:06:01.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'A', '2018-10-01 01:07:03.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'B', '2018-10-01 01:04:08.000'
GO
```

And what I am trying to populate is:

```
CREATE TABLE things1xthings2 (thing1id INT, thing2id INT)
GO
```

The rules for how rows from these two tables need to be coupled is by sequencing their datecreated values for a given parentgroup (thus the title of this post). With the example data above, the rule would play out like:

```
thing1id    thing2id
--------    --------
1           1        (matching lowest datecreated for group A)
2           3        (matching next lowest)
3           2        (matching next lowest)
4           6        (matching lowest datecreated for group B)
```

Important point: it is possible for there to be more rows for a given group in either table. The "extras" just wouldn't have a mate or a row in the cross table.

I don't know of a way to accomplish this in a single set-based JOIN operation, but if there is a way to do that, I would love to see it.

My approach was to add a column to each table:

```
ALTER TABLE things1 ADD sequence INT
GO

ALTER TABLE things2 ADD sequence INT 
GO
```

This column would essentially turn the datecreated value into an enumerated sequence that could then be matched in a set-based JOIN operation to populate the cross table:

```
INSERT INTO things1xthings2
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM things1 t1 
JOIN things2 t2 ON t2.parentgroup = t1.parentgroup
  AND t2.sequence = t1.sequence
```

The problem is I also don't know how to build the values of that sequence column. I just know the data would look like this when I'm done:

```
SELECT * FROM things1
id parentgroup datecreated             sequence
-- ----------- -----------             --------
1  A           2018-10-01 01:00:00.000 1
2  A           2018-10-01 01:00:02.000 2
3  A           2018-10-01 01:00:02.345 3
4  B           2018-10-01 01:00:01.000 1
5  B           2018-10-01 01:00:03.000 2

SELECT * FROM things2
id parentgroup datecreated             sequence
-- ----------- -----------             --------
1  A           2018-10-01 01:04:00.000 1
2  A           2018-10-01 01:05:02.345 2
3  A           2018-10-01 01:05:12.000 3
4  A           2018-10-01 01:06:01.000 4
5  A           2018-10-01 01:07:03.000 5
6  B           2018-10-01 01:04:08.000 1
```

Thanks for any help!

(Edit: My 'f' and 'd' keys were sticking!)

Comment: What database are you working with?

Comment: This is a very elaborated question! +1 from my side. You might read about `ROW_NUMBER()` with a `PARTITION BY` and an `ORDER BY` in the `OVER()`-clause. This allows for (partitioned) numbered sequences...

Comment: @GGadde This is for SQL Server 2012

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo! I was suspecting those might be part of the solution. I'll take a closer look with your suggested clauses and see if I can make something work.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to user @Shnugo for pointing me in the right direction. Using ROW_NUMBER() with a PARTITION BY and an ORDER BY in the OVER clause, I was able to make the desired associations in a single set operation, like so:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM (
    SELECT id, parentgroup, datecreated, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY parentgroup 
            ORDER BY datecreated) AS seq
    FROM things1) a
JOIN (
    SELECT id, parentgroup, datecreated, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY parentgroup 
            ORDER BY datecreated) AS seq
    FROM things2) b ON b.parentgroup = a.parentgroup 
AND b.seq = a.seq
```

Which, when run against the sample data above, produces exactly the associations desired:

```
1<->1
2<->3
3<->2
4<->6
```

Just add a simple INSERT and the table is populated exactly as needed.

Comment: Great, happy coding!